# PHPStorm Code Style: PHP in HTML

Tags: coding-style, phpstorm, reformatting

Is there a way to prevent PHPStorm 6 adding spaces after `<?=` and before `?>` in constructions like

```
<a href="<?=$variable?>">blah</a>
```

during Reformat Code (`Ctrl+Alt+L`) ?

Suddenly, it inserts spaces

```
<a href="<?= $variable ?>">blah</a>
            ^         ^
            |  here   |
```

Googling and digging Settings dialog didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17096 ?

Comment: Super annoying bug. I stopped using auto format, which I love, because of this!

Comment: Stop writing unreadable code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->PHP->Spaces->Within

Answer (score -4):

Try using the trim function in PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

By telling it to remove whitespace or something that could strip it down to its true value. I'm not too familiar with PHPStorm.

Comment: Trim will remove the value from the *contents* of the variable. This question is about the *formatting* of the code. Both examples in the OP's question should produce the same HTML in the output.